# How do you search for custom fields in Solr in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, solr

ColdFusion supports the Custom1 through Custom4 fields for Solr indexes. With Verity, you'd filter on these using cf_custom1 = 'blah', etc.

However, it appears that these cf_custom1/4 searches are not possible, and are simply ignored, when used against a solr collection.

Searching a collection for "fuel" returns the same results as searching for (cf_custom2 = fuel), or even (cf_custom20 = fuel).

My question is: how do you search the custom1 through custom4 fields on Solr Collections using cfsearch?

Answer (score 7):

the answer is to use custom2:[your value].

Thanks Scott Stroz!